# Is the clay and gravel patch method to find diamonds patched in 1.20 minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know all about the clay and gravel patch method of finding diamonds, but with it being super op, is it patched and if so, in which version of the game? Because I'm trying seeds that I myself know to work with this method in previous versions of the game but not in the latest ones and it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the method doesn't work anymore on 1.19+.

- in 1.16 clay patches give you diamond when mining in the 7th block straight down to Y=16.
- in 1.17 you have to dig counting only 3 blocks.
- in 1.18 this should still work, but now diamonds are found at deepslate level.

Well it still kinda works, but now it should send you to Lapis lazuli instead.